# How do I setup my fields for a tumblr-like blog

Tags: matrix, field

My blog has different post types, e.g. full blog post, quick status, quote, image post, how would I go about it? Is the logical way to setup a single Matrix Field with each block representing a different post type? Is there a better way of doing it?

Stating the obvious for clarity. A full blog post would have the usual stuff (title, body, image). Status has just content without a title, it's just a quick note. Quote has text and quote author and link, again no title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely would avoid using a Matrix field to add each of these types, as they'd all belong to a single entry, which isn't what you want to do (it’d get really unwieldy, really fast!).

What you're looking to do is use different [entry types](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#entry-types) in your blog settings. Each entry type can have a different field layout, so you could then switch between each.

Here’s a [blog article](http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/wrapping-your-head-around-craft-sections-and-entry-types) that covers the exact thing you’re trying to do.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I'll be using a Matrix field only in the full-blog-post entry type.